# Integrate or link to a SQL Server Management Studio Project from with a Visual Studio Solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, ssms

While most of the work for my .NET projects is done in Visual Studio, I prefer to work in SQL Server Management Studio [SSMS] (I'm currently using the 2005 version) when editing stored procedures and doing other DB-related tasks for a project.

I used to just open a ton of query Windows, commit my `alter`s, and move on, but I recently discovered Projects and Solutions within SSMS and find them to be a great way to encapsulate multiple queries/scripts that are tied to the same project.

I tried adding the SSMS project to my Visual Studio 2010 solution, but it seems that's not possible.  I'd like to include the SSMS project and/or link to it from my VS 2010 solution so that I have everything neatly grouped together in one place.  What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the kind of scripts you are executing.

If you are working with scripts that work with an SQL instance or database, you can add a new SQL Server Database Project to your Visual Studio 2010 solution. Then simply copy your scripts to the project. (SQL Server projects are included in Visual Studio 2010 Premium and Ultimate.)

Any business intelligence-related items are not (and will not be) supported by Visual Studio 2010.